# cant change my javascript to make it fit! - css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, url-rewriting

The following code changes the color of a circle, based on a number I get from a certain `<p>`:

```js
let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("centerbox");
for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    let box = boxes.item(i);
    let content = box.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
    let number = Number(content);

    if(number <= 0) {
        box.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else if(number >= 1 && number < 5) {
        box.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    } else if(number >= 5) {
        box.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}
```

```css
.centerbox {
    align-content: middle; 
    width:10px; 
    height:10px; 
    border-radius:50%;
}

.pstyle {
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:25px;
}

.widthcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="widthcontainer">
    <div class="centerbox">
      <span class="">Stock amout |</span>
      <p class="pstyle">5</p>
   </div>  
</div>
```

I cannot figure out how to style the width of the circle itself (.centerbox) since the css defines the width of the circle, which have the `<p>` inside.

I want to hear if there is a way to style the circle by itself, and then have the text from the `<span>` & `<p>` inside of it?

It's supposed to be used to tell if a certain product is in stock.

Thanks in advance! 
Andreas

Comment: make use of psuedo classes, `:before` `:after`

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! 
- could you be a bit more specific? Its been a long time since i have really coded, so im extremly rusty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pseudo-elements in your CSS to solve the problem. Here's how the CSS code looks like.

```
.centerbox::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width:10px; 
  height:10px; 
  border-radius:50%;
 }

 .green::before {
   background-color: green;
 }

 .red::before {
   background-color: red;
 }

 .yellow::before {
   background-color: yellow;
 }

.pstyle {
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left:25px;
}

.widthcontainer{
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

You then add the classes to your elements, Here's how the JS code looks like :

```
let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("centerbox")
for(let i = 0;i<boxes.length;i++){
  let box = boxes.item(i)
  let content = box.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML
  let number = Number(content)
  if(number <= 0) {
    box.classList.add("red");
  }
  else
  if(number >= 1 && number <5){
   box.classList.add("yellow");
  }

  else
  if(number >=5){
   box.classList.add("green");
  }

}
```

The HTML stays the same :

```
<div class="widthcontainer">
  <div class="centerbox">
    <span class="">Stock amout |</span> <p class="pstyle">10</p>
 </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seemed to do the trick! You are a life saver mate!